# Unclear about returning from javascript forEach loop inside a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to understand the fundamentals of some js concepts, specifically on why my function returns on defined value

accountName is just a simple string, like "facebook"
the return value of accounts is just an array

Original Function

```
function getAccount(accountName) {
    var accounts = Storage.getItemSync('accounts');
    var matchedAccount
    for(account in accounts){
      if (account.name === accountName){
        matchedAccount =  accountName;
      }
    }

   return matchedAccount;
}
```

Working Version

```
function getAccount(accountName) {
    var accounts = Storage.getItemSync('accounts');
    var matchedAccount

    accounts.forEach(function(account) {
        if(account.name === accountName){
            matchedAccount = account
        }
    });
    return matchedAccount;

}
```

The original function returns Undefined, while the working version returns the correct results. Why is this happening? Arn't I iterating over my array all the same?

Comment: Hint: read the documentation of `for..in`

Comment: Also read up on [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple but still a good question.
In Javascript `forEach` works on Arrays while `(for x in y)` work on Objects*

while for..in does work on Arrays, because it enumerates through object fields, not indexes.

see this answer: [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)

MDN docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: ah I got it. Make sense, my account.name is not a part of the enumerable property of the accounts array. I logged both account and account.name, one returns 0, the other returns undefined. Which makes senses from what I read in the docs and that link. for.. in is iterating my array indices! Thanks!